# Switching between product category cards

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, onclick, onblur

I have cards with categories, clicking on which opens hidden content. I need the card to close when switching between them and if a click occurs behind the content.

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import s from "./Shop.module.css";
import { useState } from "react";

export const Shop = () => {
  const card = [
    {
      name: "Brands",
      cat: ["Adidas", "Nike", "Reebok", "Puma", "Vans", "New Balance"],
      show: false,
      id: 0,
    },
    {
      name: "Size",
      cat: ["43", "43,5"],
      show: false,
      id: 1,
    },
    {
      name: "Type",
      cat: ["Sneakers ", "Slippers"],
      show: false,
      id: 2,
    },
  ];
  const [active, setActive] = useState({});
  const handleActive = (id) => {
    setActive({ ...active, [id]: !active[id] });
  };
  const handleDisable = (index) => {
    setActive(index);
  };

  return (
    <div className={s.container}>
      <div className={s.brandInner}>
        {card.map((i, index) => {
          return (
            <div className={s.brandCard} key={i.id}>
              <button
                className={`${s.brandBtn} `}
                onClick={() => handleActive(i.id, index)}
                onBlur={() => handleDisable(index)}
              >
                <p className={`${active[i.id] ? `${s.brandBtnActive}` : ``}`}>
                  {i.name}
                </p>
              </button>
              <div
                className={`${s.openCard} ${active[i.id] ? "" : `${s.dNone}`}`}
              >
                <ul className={s.brandList}>
                  {i.cat.map((elem) => {
                    return (
                      <li key={elem} className={s.brandItem}>
                        {elem}
                      </li>
                    );
                  })}
                </ul>
                <button className={s.brandOpenBtn}>Apply</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I tried to do it through onBlur, but this way I can't interact with the content that appears when opening the card, please help

Comment: Try to add the `onBlur` in the `<div className={s.brandCard} key={i.id} onBlur={() => handleDisable(index)}>`

Comment: I tried, it doesn't work, everything is exactly the same...

Comment: Try to add the `onMouseLeave` in the `<div className={s.brandCard} key={i.id} onMouseLeave={() => handleDisable(index)}>`

Comment: It helped, but it's not exactly what I wanted to achieve initially. But thanks for the advice anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this a few different ways, here are two.

#### Array version

You can do this by using a array to keep track of the ids that are active.

```js
const [active, setActive] = useState([]);
```

For the event handler we will creata a new `toggleActive` function which replaces the others. This will check if the `id` is already in the array and if so remove it, else add it.

```js
const toggleActive = (id) => {
  setActive((prevActive) => {
    if (prevActive.includes(id)) {
      return prevActive.filter((activeId) => activeId !== id);
    }
    return [...prevActive, id];
  });
};
```

Then in the return of the component we need to updated some logic as well. Then handlers only take in the `id` of the `i`. To check if the `id` is in the array with can use `includes`.

```js
<button
  className={s.brandBtn}
  onClick={() => toggleActive(i.id)}
>
  <p className={`${active.includes(i.id) ? s.brandBtnActive : ""}`}>
    {i.name}
  </p>
</button>
<div
  className={`${s.openCard} ${active.includes(i.id) ? "" : s.dNone}`}
>
```

#### Object version

This version is to do it with a object.

```js
const [active, setActive] = useState({});
```

The handler, this will toggle the value of the `id` starting with false if there is no value for the **id** yet.

```js
const toggleActive = (id) => {
  setActive((prevActive) => {
    const prevValue = prevActive[id] ?? false;
    return {
      ...prevActive,
      [id]: !prevValue,
    };
  });
};
```

The elements

```js
<button
  className={s.brandBtn}
  onClick={() => toggleActive(i.id)}
>
  <p className={`${active[i.id] ? s.brandBtnActive : ""}`}>
    {i.name}
  </p>
</button>
<div
  className={`${s.openCard} ${active[i.id] ? "" : s.dNone}`}
>
```

### Edit: toggle with closing others

First we declare the state with a initial value of `null`

```js
const [active, setActive] = useState(null)
```

We create the toggleActive function which checks if the `id` to toggle is the previous id, if so return null else return the new active id

```js
  const toggleActive = (id) => {
    setActive((prevActive) => {
      if (prevActive === id) return null;
      return id;
    });
  };
```

For the rendering it is quite simple, add the `toggleActive` function to the button and check if the `active` is the same **id**

```js
<button
  className={s.brandBtn}
  onClick={() => toggleActive(i.id)}
>
  <p className={`${active === i.id ? s.brandBtnActive : ""}`}>
    {i.name}
  </p>
</button>
<div
  className={`${s.openCard} ${active === i.id ? "" : s.dNone}`}
>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I still can't interact with the content that opens when you click on the button. When you try to select a category, everything closes

Comment: I updated the answer, it has now toggle functionality @PePorMaty

Comment: Thank you very much! Can you also please do what if one button is already open, when opening the next one, the previous one closes? I.e. if the Brands button is open and when clicking on another button, for example Type, the Brand button closes. I will be very grateful. And also if the click occurs outside the open card